# Finding a limit of integral involving $n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let for $n \geq 0$,

$$I_n = \frac{1}{\pi^n} \int^{\pi}_{0} x^n e^x \sin x dx, \quad  J_n = \frac{1}{\pi^n} \int^{\pi}_{0} x^n e^x \cos x dx,$$

then you can get:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} J_n = 0.$$

and the reccurence formulae yield:

$$I_n = -\frac{\pi}{n+1} J_{n+1}- \frac{2\pi}{n+1} I_{n+1}, \quad J_n =- \frac{\pi e^\pi}{n+1} - \frac{\pi}{n+1} (J_{n+1} - I_{n+1}).$$

They give the conclusion:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n^2I_n = \pi^2 e^\pi,\quad \lim_{n \to \infty} n J_n = -\pi e^\pi$$

But I want to go further, espesially I tried to find the limit below.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n(n^2 I_n + \pi n J_n) $$

I tried to use the formulae above but expressions got more and more complicated and my hand out. Wolfram alpha gave -1173.05 $\dots$　but what exactly is this number?

Comment: Umm... Can't you just use the linearity of the limit for the last step?

Comment: Perhaps useful: Wolfram finds closed forms for the following Mellin transforms
$$\mathcal{M}(\exp\cdot\sin)(s)=\pi\frac{2^{-s/2}\sin(\pi s/4)}{\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s)}$$
$$\mathcal{M}(\exp\cdot\cos)(s)=\pi\frac{2^{-s/2-2}}{\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s/4)\cos(\pi s/2)}$$

Comment: Perhaps $-π^2(2+π)e^π = -1174.2...$?

Comment: I think you meant the negative of that?